# IntelliJ Idea code coverage not working in editor

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea after running tests with coverage I don't see color indicators  in the editor. I tried different code coverage tools (Intellij, Emma, JaCoCo), but result is the same. On clean project setup everything works.
Does it needs to be additional configured or it's a bug in Idea?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in IDEA, so [you should report it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=jacoco%20emma).

Be sure to include enough information to reproduce the problem. In your case, make a copy of your project and repeatedly remove irrelevant files, until you finally come to a point where everything works.